# Hours are off by 4

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I'm trying to display the difference between two dates, broken down in months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds. The code below seems to work except the hours is always off by 4. I tried both HOUR and HOUR_OF_DAY, but get the same results.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);


    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

    try {
        //get the current date/time
        Date beginDate = cal.getTime();

        //fabricate a future date/time
        Date endDate = dateFormat.parse(String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf(month)
                + "-" + String.valueOf(day+95) + " " + String.valueOf(hour+2)
                + ":" + String.valueOf(minutes +16) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds +34));

        long millis = endDate.getTime() - beginDate.getTime();

        TextView txtMonths = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.months);
        txtMonths.setText("Months: " + (new SimpleDateFormat("M")).format(new Date(millis)));

        TextView txtDays = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.days);
        txtDays.setText("Days: " + (new SimpleDateFormat("d")).format(new Date(millis)));

        TextView txtHours = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hours);
        txtHours.setText("Hours: " + (new SimpleDateFormat("h")).format(new Date(millis)));

        TextView txtMinutes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
        txtMinutes.setText("Minutes: " + (new SimpleDateFormat("m")).format(new Date(millis)));

        TextView txtSeconds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
        txtSeconds.setText("Seconds: " + (new SimpleDateFormat("s")).format(new Date(millis)));

    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Log.d("ParseException", ex.toString());

    }
```

It was suggested it is because of TimeZone. I am GMT +8 and DST = true so

```
 TimeZone timeZone = cal.getTimeZone();
 timeZone.getOffset( System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Returns 7 hours not 4. Am I missing something with TimeZone info?

Comment: You are not taking time zones into account, I imagine.

Comment: Check that timezones is not the issue. Consistently off by 4 hours sounds like it might be the case.

Comment: Yes, time zone. Thanks. I am GMT +8. Wonder where it comes up with 4.

Comment: get all DTs in GMT and add offset + dst? Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();int offGMT = cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS WRONG
I thought I had it, but I don't.

I think it was timezone, but I'm still not sure how it came up with 4 when I am GMT+8 and in DST. So, while the code below seems to work I would feel more comfortable if it had been off by 7 or 8. If that had been the case timezone would have dawned on me immediately.

Java can be brutal.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone UTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    cal.setTimeZone(UTC);

    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);


    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

    try {
        //get the current date/time
        Date beginDate = cal.getTime();

        //fabricate a future date/time

        endDate = dateFormat.parse(String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf(month)
                + "-" + String.valueOf(day+95) + " " + String.valueOf(hour+2)
                + ":" + String.valueOf(minutes +1) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds +34));
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(UTC);

        long millis = endDate.getTime() - beginDate.getTime();

        if (TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime( new Date())) {
            millis += 3600000;
        }

        TextView txtMonths = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.months);
        txtMonths.setText("Months: " + (new SimpleDateFormat("M")).format(new Date(millis)));

        TextView txtDays = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.days);
        txtDays.setText("Days: " + (new SimpleDateFormat("d")).format(new Date(millis)));

        TextView txtHours = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hours);
        txtHours.setText("Hours: " + (new SimpleDateFormat("h")).format(new Date(millis)));

        TextView txtMinutes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
        txtMinutes.setText("Minutes: " + (new SimpleDateFormat("m")).format(new Date(millis)));

        TextView txtSeconds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
        txtSeconds.setText("Seconds: " + (new SimpleDateFormat("s")).format(new Date(millis)));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Log.d("ParseException", ex.toString());

    }
```